# Installing Clipbucket

Tags: xampp

Help me with my Clip Bucket !
Error, I am using Xamp server on Windows 8 RT
The error is below:

`Prechecking`

Clipbucket requires following modules in order to work properly, we
   are performing some initial search to find modules. Click here for
   why we need these modules PHP

Notice: Undefined variable: php_ver in
   C:\xampp\htdocs\Clipbucket\cb_install\modes\precheck.php on line 11
   FFMPEG

Notice: Undefined variable: ffmpeg_ver in
   C:\xampp\htdocs\Clipbucket\cb_install\modes\precheck.php on line 14
   FLVtool2

Notice: Undefined variable: flvtool2_ver in
   C:\xampp\htdocs\Clipbucket\cb_install\modes\precheck.php on line 17
   MP4Box

Notice: Undefined variable: mp4boxver in
   C:\xampp\htdocs\Clipbucket\cb_install\modes\precheck.php on line 21
   cURL

Notice: Undefined variable: curlver in
   C:\xampp\htdocs\Clipbucket\cb_install\modes\precheck.php on line 24
   PHPShield

Notice: Undefined variable: phpshield in
   C:\xampp\htdocs\Clipbucket\cb_install\modes\precheck.php on line 27

Thank you guys...will need serious help

Comment: Welcome Eric, you'll probably get more attention (and help)  if you make your title something more descriptive. Hopefully someone comes and helps out that has a 8rt as well.

Comment: How did you even manage to install XAMPP on WinRT? I don't think an ARM version is available.

Comment: Which page are you visiting to get those notices? It might not be intended to be visited directly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I rather doubt you're running it on windows RT - windows RT won't run unsigned code, and anything not on the microsoft market.

As for the errors, it basically means that you're missing software that Clipbucket relies on. You need to download and install these somewhere that XAMPP is aware of.

If you were on a linux system, this would be a simple matter of installing most of these off a package manager. On windows, it involves finding or compiling these, and likely putting these in a folder you've added to path.